# nginx how to proxy_pass all requests expect one directory?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

What I'm trying to do is that all incoming requests shall be handled by my Angular application. But one directory is for a REST-api that have to be excluded.

My current nginx config locks like this:

```
location /rest {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rest/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

The above config **always** responds with the `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. The REST api itself seems to work, because when I disable the `location ~ /` the REST is called and returns content. So what I would like to achieve is:

```
https://SERVER       -> http://127.0.0.1:4000
https://SERVER/xyz   -> http://127.0.0.1:4000
...
https://SERVER/rest  -> http://127.0.0.1/rest
```

How can do a proxy forward off all requests but not if a specific directory is given?

Comment: `location ~ /` is a regular expression location that matches anything. Perhaps you meant to use `location /` which is the default location that only matches URIs which are not handled by another location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Also, you might try to ask this on https://serverfault.com/, You might find an answer easier there...

Comment: Are all requests to `/rest/...` always served with the same script, `/rest/index.php`? Or there can be requests for some static content or other PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1):

What I would first try is to modify the first rule as:

```
location ^~ /rest {...
```

According to the info here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

This should ensure that the sercond block is not encoutered if the first matches:

> If the longest matching prefix location has the ^~ modifier, then
> Nginx will immediately end its search and select this location to
> serve the request.

Comment: That really seems to work. Thx! But now the index.php file is downloaded but not executed. Any further idea?

Comment: The problem here, is that nginx does not do php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398281/how-to-use-nginx-with-php

I would use PHP-FPM.

Comment: Therefore I inserted a PH rule. Please see my last answer